# When I parse an XSLT in a context where the input and output are SAX, is a DOM tree created behind the scenes?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, sax, xalan

Here is example code I am referring to:

http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/usagepatterns.html#sax

First, notice that everything that can be SAX-based is SAX-based in this code: both the input and the output.

Also, notice that a transformerHandler object is created off of "foo.xsl" and that transformerHandler is used to do a transformation from the SAX input to the SAX ContentHandler that creates the output.

I had understood that XSLT requires something like a DOM tree to be built in order for it to do its work.

So here is my question: I wonder if the transformerHandler is actually building something like a DOM tree behind the scenes?  If it is, doesn't that kind of defeat the purpose of trying so hard to stay in SAX-land?

Comment: I found this:

[http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/dtm.html](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/dtm.html)

which seems to suggest that they use something like VTD-XML behind the scenes.  This is much more efficient than a DOM tree and makes sense in the context.

I'll leave this up for a while and see if anyone else comes up with a more definitive answer.

Comment: It is done in one phase - you do not get access to the process while it is runing. The point was, that it requires a new instatiation, for every new document. When I do this NOT using SAX, I can (re)use the same processor over and over. If you already have a DOM instance, this can be parsed, like a prepared input - it will save some overhead - because it does not need to do a parse from META to DOM

Comment: It all depends on the stylesheet and the transformer internal implementation (how many clever optimizations the author(s) managed to squeeze in to it). I refer to this article, http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xslt2/, about the internal design of an early Saxon. If you read it I think you will appreciate that "staying in SAX-land" can be beneficial.

Comment: Per Norman, Thanks.  It looks like Saxon also uses something like VTD-XML (which they call com.icl.saxon.tinytree) to avoid creating a DOM tree.  Very interesting.  user639175, looks like I'll need to do some performance testing.  I'm expecting that the closer I can stay to SAX-land, the better I'll be (in my particular application).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/dtm.html

> The Document Table Model (DTM) is an interface to a Document Model designed specifically for the needs of our XPath and XSLT implementations. The motivation behind this model is to optimize performance and minimize storage.
>
> Specifically, DTM avoids the overhead of instantiating the objects the standard DOM requires to represent a tree of nodes. DTM uses unique integer "handles" to identify nodes, integer ID values to represent URLs, local names, and expanded names, and integer index and length references to a string buffer to represent the text value of each node.

In other words, it doesn't build a DOM tree but it builds an efficient structure that is specially suited to meet the needs of XSLT.